# use of isDefaultPrevented() with custom events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i was just going through the [carasoul.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L132) code and came across the following lines of code :

```
if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return
```

now the documentation of `isDefaultPrevented()` gives the foolowing example :

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  alert( event.isDefaultPrevented() ); // false
  event.preventDefault();
  alert( event.isDefaultPrevented() ); // true
});
```

but i am not attaching a `click event` so how is `isDefaultPrevented` of any assists here ? , the entire function code can be seen below ::

```
 Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active)
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var that      = this

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
          }, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }
```

Why the use of `isDefaultPrevented()` ?

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap carousel triggers events at interesting moments, for example before and after it slides. If you want to do something when these events happen, you can react to them like so:

```
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    // do something before a carousel slides
});
```

And if you want to prevent the carousel from it's default behaviour, you can do that like so:

```
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    // prevent the carousel from sliding
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Bootstrap then checks if an event handler called `preventDefault()` and stops its default behaviour if it happened:

```
if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return
```